# When can negative numbers be taken as representatives in modular arithmetic?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I'm wondering about a step in the [Lucas probable prime test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_pseudoprime#Implementing_a_Lucas_probable_prime_test):

$V_{2k}=V_k^2-2Q^k$

The Wikipedia article states: At each stage, we reduce $U$, $V$, and the power of $Q$, mod $n$. Depending on whether or not you take the negative number after reducing mod n, the result may be different. For example

Assume $Q$ is negative, such as $-3$. The first U and V are 1. Then $V_2=1-2(-3)^1=1+6=7$ However if you reduce $Q^k$ mod n (where n is positive) one may get the "wrong" answer. For example assume $n=5$ then $-3 \equiv 2(mod5)$ which gives $V_2=1-2(2)=-3$

This might be a non-issue because the test checks if the final term is congruent to 0, which isn't signed. Since it's a sequence the result is used to compute the next term so it's important to know which value to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ending result will be the correct value modulo $\ n\ $, no matter whether we choose negative or positive residues , as long as they are correct modulo $\ n\ $. So, the signs do not cause a problem.

Comment: Can you explain how the end result is correct if intermediate terms in the sequence are "wrong"?

Comment: I do not understand why they should be wrong. Modulo $\ n\ $, we should get the same result in each step.

Comment: Is my example unclear? Taking the negative residue results in $V_2=7$ but taking the positive results in $-3$. When calculating the next term in the sequence, how do you know to use $7$ or $-3$?

Comment: modulo $5$, $-3$ and $7$ are equal. So, if we , for example multiply them with $2$, we get $-6$ and $14$ which again are equal modulo $5$. I see no operations we make which depend on the choice of the representant.

Comment: I agree they are equal but this changes the value of the term in the next sequence

Comment: If $V_k$ and $Q^k$ have the correct value modulo $n$, we calculate $V_{2k}$ modulo $n$ correctly as well, no matter which number we have after this step.

Comment: not if you fully reduce into least positive form. $-3\equiv 2$ and $7\equiv 2$ in the mod 5 case.